# SQLite Copying data to second table from first table

Tags: python, sqlite

I have two tables created from below query in SQLite:

CREATE TABLE people (
  id integer unique primary key,
  first_name text,
  middle_name text,
  last_name text,
  email text,
  phone text
);

CREATE TABLE companies (
  id integer unique primary key,
  name text,
  url text,
  contact integer,
  FOREIGN KEY(contact) REFERENCES people(id)
);

I have all the data available in the first table, but I want to popup id in second table same as id in the first table.name in the companies table is concatenated string of first_name text,middle_name,last_name in people table.
I want something like "UPDATE companies SET contact = (SELECT people.id FROM people WHERE companies.name = people.first_name || "," || "people.second_name"; it will be great if I can show the string in people table is the subset of string in companies table
I am a beginner in python and SQlite both.

Comment: You can do this with just a plain SQL INSERT statement. No need for python.

Comment: Can you please guide for the sql statement?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html